# Bash script is working only in path where is bash script file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, filter, last-modified

I want to get last one (newest) file in the directory. And this script is working for the directory where I have bash file.
When I changed the path to another path problem is in `last_modified`. Script can't see `file` - I think but I don't know why. Can anybody help?

Below is code in my test.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(cd '/path_where_is_test.sh_file' && ls -t | head -1)
last_modified=$(stat -c %Y $file)
current=$(date +%s)

if (( ($current - $last_modified) > 86400 )); then
    echo 'Mail'
else
    echo 'No Mail'
fi;
```

Comment: You are changing directory but then when calling Stat, you are back in the original directory. So you have to add the path to stat as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `ls` after `cd` to a particular directory. The output of `ls` is just a file name without a path. Later you pass that file name without path to the `stat` command. If your current directory is different, then `stat` won't find the file.

Possible solutions:

- Add the directory (`dir`) to the `stat` command

  ```
  dir='/path_where_is_test.sh_file'
  file=$(cd "$dir" && ls -t | head -1)
  last_modified=$(stat -c %Y "$dir/$file")
  ```
- Use the changed directory

  ```
  last_modified=$(cd '/path_where_is_test.sh_file' && stat -c %Y $(ls -t | head -1))
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)